# How to properly set the content of an IFile in Eclipse plugin when the editor is opened

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm using the following code to set the content of an IFile:

```
public static IFile updateFile(IFile file, String content) {
    if (file.exists()) {
        InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());

        try {
            file.setContents(source, IResource.FORCE, new NullProgressMonitor());

            source.close();
        } catch (CoreException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return file;
}
```

This works fine when the file is not opened in the editor, but if the file is opened I get the following warning as if the file was modified outside of Eclipse:

[image]

I tried to refresh the file (by calling `refreshLocal()` method) before and after calling `setContents()` but that didn't help.

Is there a way to avoid this warning?

Comment: That isn't a warning that the file was modified outside Eclipse, just outside the Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your method in a `WorkspaceModifyOperation`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looks like that runs the operation in a batch in a different thread but I still get the same warning

Comment: Yes, after calling setContents() I can see that the editor is dirty

Comment: No, I mean before you actually touch the file.

Comment: Is this an editor class of your own? A non-dirty editor should just refresh automatically.

Comment: No, it is a .json file opened in the JSON editor that comes with Eclipse

Comment: It depends on the exact design of the editor, some just always display this message.

Comment: As @greg-449 points out, as well as your original question, it's not an error, just unusual for a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

The editor reaction looks correct, because there is a modification outside of org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument that bound to the editor instance.

The right approach will be to modify not the file content, but an instance of "model" that represents the file content, something like `IJavaElement` for JDT.

Also you can try to manipulate the document content directly (needs polishing for production):

```
        IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
        for (IWorkbenchWindow window : windows) {
            IWorkbenchPage[] pages = window.getPages();
            for (IWorkbenchPage page : pages) {
                IEditorReference[] editorReferences = page.getEditorReferences();
                for (IEditorReference editorReference : editorReferences) {
                    IEditorPart editorPart = editorReference.getEditor(false/*do not restore*/);
                    IEditorInput editorInput = editorPart.getEditorInput();
//skip editors that are not related
                    if (inputAffected(editorInput)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (editorPart instanceof AbstractTextEditor) {
                        AbstractTextEditor textEditor = (AbstractTextEditor) editorPart;
                        IDocument document = textEditor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(editorInput);
                        document.set(content);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Honestly, I do not understand the scenario you are trying to cover, probably there are better ways to do this.